# Surreal numbers and the Collatz iteration as a game?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, surreal-numbers, collatz-conjecture

Let us define a game based on the Collatz function $C(n) = n/2$ if $n$ is even, otherwise $=3n+1$.

Each number $n$ represents a game played by left $L$ and right $R$:

$$n = \{L_n | R_n \}$$

The rules of the game are:

If $n$ is even, the left player can play the game:

$$n = \{n/2 | \emptyset \}$$

If $n \neq 1$ is odd, the right player can play the game:

$$n = \{\emptyset| 3n+1 \}$$

If $n=1$, the game is over as no player can make a move:

$$n = \{\emptyset| \emptyset \}$$

Assuming the Collatz conjecture, this game starting with an arbitrary number $n$, has always an end.

So these games define surreal numbers and we could add and multiply, negate those games, which I think would be fun.

**Q: How do I find the numeric value of these surreal numbers? Is there an algorithm to do this?**

Example:

```
x7  =  (frozenset(), frozenset({x22}))
x22  =  (frozenset({x11}), frozenset())
x11  =  (frozenset(), frozenset({x34}))
x34  =  (frozenset({x17}), frozenset())
x17  =  (frozenset(), frozenset({x52}))
x52  =  (frozenset({x26}), frozenset())
x26  =  (frozenset({x13}), frozenset())
x13  =  (frozenset(), frozenset({x40}))
x40  =  (frozenset({x20}), frozenset())
x20  =  (frozenset({x10}), frozenset())
x10  =  (frozenset({x5}), frozenset())
x5  =  (frozenset(), frozenset({x16}))
x16  =  (frozenset({x8}), frozenset())
x8  =  (frozenset({x4}), frozenset())
x4  =  (frozenset({x2}), frozenset())
x2  =  (frozenset({x1}), frozenset())
x1  =  (frozenset(), frozenset())
```

sorted by value:

```
[1, 5, 13, 17, 11, 7, 9, 2, 10, 26, 34, 22, 14, 4, 20, 52, 28, 8, 40, 16]
```

[Example Sage-Math-Script.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJydVctq3DAU3fsr1IGCnLhJZrIIDXhVuiiYLKZdBIwJzkjTiJFlI3kmskv_vVeSX_I8AvVKurrn3HMfkgndok3JeV63WISPAYKPbZH4vIrjO7c1n6T1XgokblfWRLmiR4f3V-J6aY0BAVbOVP1txsw5ilGa2fX7G-MUiU_xcmTi_CavKioIIAajAMwoMZj72YATGRDDWKwGtZeS5vykDF9fTyvpgUpFsTMoBY5__tr1tpSIISaQzMVvijkVmPMwHMUXhpSnLBssUMginubnONNlBq54K8uWCkVrnGZh5O3G5Ck3JLNudDTFnMbYblfZJbZp387R-HjwuL8qrpdZT9TVWSlXY7EvXqFk8xoTAqyEbSzf2YafGDXzPQP2kEu80ItrVUsgDb3zp5liz_d2FYbnS9BPVD_KQ1mGOfpfEX7MKdLeDCPqWMZ4aVzR0mfTjafgjACn8HLkPoxP1nWNENc1ppLyncpfb7nAOmq6pukk0muAaLtrkqgxu8bNP5PmwgjCalYa6TnnOBVl7XE1keahvSuam8uik677im4A-zFeRtrhG2nwzTrzpm6mIhdkzuzy25RFlUs6yY0dJ23hM_Xh0bt2dxF-ogDHFF-W55_N7sm0qnNCfvqSdRx7rT2CN71n85Gn_rDFbQLLCYmTw02qJzpqvdvkZi-g6tNxHNLoJqGxuCZB_WS261Nx5BDHdl73nbfe7fpCHOlPzBjH3JM2idq1N0NtANUm9-Zw9oP4CkA4-SEO_ePVsgqD5eaQ8z1VOIzMZkcbWIKvibozQcHq6l1JJmq8Q9ECGBbGO91BHgHILtB2LzZ1WXKFWFGVskabonqpyxfgCwJYmx_dYMHdCAPYkS4UQChBrw2yah4XYXeSOs3pIbN1OBhFztnXDqwxBAizkfO7zouKWy4hTElmz_nDJElw8JKMkEvSHJgs_wE3zVsq&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

**Edit**:
A slightly more interesting example game with numerical values occur, if we use $T(n) = (3n+1)/2$ if $n$ is odd, $n/2$ otherwise instead.

Here are some examples, but I do not see any pattern, where $v(n)$ denotes the numerical value of $n$:

$n,v(n)$

```
1 0
2 1
3 -1
4 2
5 0
6 0
7 -2
8 3
9 -1
10 1
11 -1
12 1
13 0
14 0
15 -3
16 4
17 0
18 0
19 -1
20 2
21 0
22 0
23 -2
24 2
25 -1
26 1
```

Comment: also asked on MSE since I am not sure if it is research level: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892271/conways-surreal-numbers-and-the-collatz-iteration-as-a-game

Comment: Has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3892462/828802

Comment: Answer of the edited question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3893731/a-followup-question-on-surreal-numbers-and-collatz-iteration-game